# Function and function group with same name in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have following object in `JavaScript`. I am confused in how to access `object.demo()` and `object.demo.inner()`. The `object.demo.inner()` worked fine but `object.demo` is not working. I have the requirement that the name should be same. Why is the function not overloading here?

```
var object = {
    // object.demo()
    demo: function(str, pathStr) {
        console.log('function 1')
    },

    demo: {
         // object.demo.inner()
        inner: function () {
            console.log('inner')
        }
    }
}

object.demo.inner() //working
object.demo() //not working
```

Comment: And how are you supposed to differentiate `object.demo` which is a function to `object.demo` which is an object ?

Comment: You can not have same property name for multiple properties, there must be only one named `StartingNoob` unless you add any prefix or suffix

Comment: what should be done for both of these to work?  object.demo.inner(), object.demo()

Comment: See @dfsq answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function is an object in javascript so it can have other properties. So you can assign `inner` function to a property of `object.demo` object:

```
var object = {
    // object.demo()
    demo: function(str, pathStr) {
        console.log('function 1')
    }
}

// object.demo.inner
object.demo.inner = function () {
    console.log('inner')
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is no function `object.demo`, because you are overwriting the same object with another object. This behaviour is prohibited in ES5 with [`'strict mode'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors), but not in ES6.

You could take the outer object and assign the function to the `inner` property later.

```js
var object = {
    demo: function(str, pathStr) {
        console.log('function 1')
    }
};

object.demo.inner = function () { console.log('inner'); };

object.demo.inner();
object.demo();
```